# distorted shapes and curves

Tags: adobe-illustrator, shapes

I did a project a while ago where all the curves and a lot of the shapes were distorted.  Unfortunately I only noticed the distortion after having saved the file.  I am attempting to fix the issue now and from what I understand the issue might be a case of extreme scaling (huge size, scaled down by A LOT).

My question is, would it be possible to fix and 'heal' my drawing?

In case I have to redo the whole thing what should I do to prevent the same thing happening again?

[image: you can see how all the circles and round shapes are messed up, and how all the orthogonal lines are distorted.]
[image: these were a pattern of squares and rectangles, and it is completely destroyed with even some lines missing in parts.]

I have Adobe CS5.1 just in case that information was needed.

I appreciate any help.

EDIT: On the first Picture all the curves and circles are turned into hexagons and edged shapes.  you can see the 'chairs' are distorted, and the lines that were parallel are all messed up.

On the second picture a pattern of squares and rectangles that were set on a 45 degree angle is completely out of wack.

Comment: "Adobe CS5.1" is not the name of your drawing software – Adobe is the company name. Is it perhaps "Adobe Illustrator CS5.1"? If so, please tag accordingly.

Comment: It is hard to tell what the problem is but it sort of looks like you had "align to pixel grid" selected and all your corners where snapped to the closest pixel value. If you give us more info on what you are calling a distortion and the settings of your file and tools, we might be able to help. Otherwise the question is unclear.

Comment: I have added an explanation of the distortion to the original question.  I checked, Align to Pixel Grid is not checked.

Comment: I have no idea on what happen **IF** it was all handled as an Ilustrator file. 
In my opinion it looks that at some point you exported that as another format like DWG or something.

Answer (score 1):

An explanation of what is *wrong* with that image wouldn't hurt. I mean.... none of us saw the original. :)

Options to watch:

- **Scale Stokes and Effects** (turn this off if you want stroke weights to remain consistent)
- **Align to Pixel Grid** (Turn this off if you aren't creating images for pixel-based displays)

Just my guessing... looks like **Scale Strokes & Effects** was on before you scaled. So stroke weights got reduced a great deal for some items when you reduced their size. You can *easily* fix that by selecting the items and resetting the stroke weight.

Of course, in some cases you may need to redraw because at smaller sizes spaces also get smaller and the space between 2, 1pt strokes may not be enough clearance.

Another tip is try and always work at the same, comfortable, size for you - whether that's large or small doesn't matter. If you tend to stick to relatively the same basic size when creating things, combining elements from different files gets easier and things aren't so wildly different in aspect ratios.

Answer (score 0):

The warping might be a result of you not smoothing the curves or a bug in the software. I haven't encountered this exact problem before but a similar kind in 3D modelling. Look on the forums if there is bug associated with smoothing and try to fix the issue.

Hope this helps.